# Where do I find thread?

Tags: tinker-island

I need thread to upgrade my storage, but so far none of my map locations have it. I know it is something that I find (the tooltip says to search prior locations), but all my prior locations I have so far don't list it as something I can find there.

Where can I find thread?

Answer (score 1):

Thread can be found in the Delta, which is on the right side of the map, near the Caverns.

*[Source](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/35472-general/topics/639650-where-thread)*

Comment: Hm, looks like I'm not there yet, so I am going to have to be patient. :(